# How to search for word in text file and print the entire line with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

The code i have right:

```py
with open("text.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if "Hello" in part:
                print(part)
```

Can only find a specific word like hello in the text an print it.
The problem is, i want it to stop printing only that word and print the entire line that has the word in it.
How can i do that?

This is the result im getting right now:

```
hello
hello
hello
```

Whreas, the text document includes:

```
hello, i am a code
hello, i am a coder
hello, i am a virus
```

Comment: Python 2.7 has reached EoL on 2020/01/01, I would suggest you moving to Python 3. In this code, only `print something` would have to be changed to `print(something)`

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that. I think i am using python 3, because I got a parenthesis error when I used the code. Im used to python 2.7 too much.

Comment: Updated your question and @GustaveCoste answer to use Python 3 `print` function instead of Python 2 `print` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just do a non necessary for loop, try this:

```
with open("text.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if "Hello" in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you, but right now, it's putting a blank line between each printing, how could we stop that?

Comment: Use `print(line.strip())` to remove leading and trailing whitespaces (\n is a whitespace too)

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention that the word "hello" is LowerCase in your example, therefore, for catching also upper and lowercases I would recommend this modified piece of code:

```
with open("text.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if "hello" in line.lower():
            print(line)
```